# Проблема с нахождением элементов из-за Namespace в xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

имеется некая xml. В коде я получаю XElement. Затем пишу следующий код:

```
 string value= Document.Element("FirstElement").With( e => e.Element( "InnerElement") ).With( e => e.Value ) 

<RootElement>
  <FirstElement>
    <InnerElement>
        InnerElementValue
    </InnerElement>
  </FirstElement>
```

В данном случае все отрабатывает нормально. Значение получаю. Но появилась необходимость немного изменить структуру xml, чтобы она выглядела следующим образом:

```
<RootElement xmlns="http://somenamespace.ru">
<FirstElement>
    <InnerElement>
        InnerElementValue
    </InnerElement>
</FirstElement>
```

В коде я добавляю пространство имен следующим образом:

```
Document.Root.Add( nsAtr );//nsAtr берется из xsd-схемы
foreach ( var item in Document.Root.DescendantsAndSelf() )
                item.Name = ns + item.Name.LocalName; //XNamespace ns = nsAtr.Value;
```

где Document - XDocument.

Теперь предыдущий код по получения значения перестал работать. Во время отладки навожу на Document и вижу что структура xml-документа, такая, какая быть и должна. Выполняя в ImmediateWindow Document.FirstNode.NextNode. я получаю следующее:

```
<FirstElement xmlns="http://somenamespace.ru">
```

Хотя если скопировать весь документ из XML Visualizer ничего подобного нет. пространство имен видно только у корневого элемента. 
Тогда я сделал следующее:

```
var xFirstElement= XName.Get( "FirstElement", "http://somenamespace.ru" );
var xInnerElement= XName.Get( "InnerElement", "http://somenamespace.ru" );
string value= Document.Element(xFirstElement).With( e => e.Element( xInnerElement) ).With( e => e.Value )
```

И тогда получение значение снова заработало. Но реальный xml документ, с которым приходится работать гораздо больше и сложней, и мест в программе, работающим с ним, очень много. Поэтому такой подход мне не очень как-то подходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что вообще произошло и как можно с эти бороться. Я так понимаю, что в коде добавляется пространство имен для всех элементов, хотя почему-то отображается оно только на корневом элементе. Каким образом можно добавить пространство имен только в корень? я пробовал просто

```
Document.Root.Add( nsAtr );//nsAtr берется из xsd-схемы
```

но программа выдала ошибку мне.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что пространство имен по умолчанию (а в вашем документе объявлено именно оно) наследуется дочерними элементами. Кроме того, вы же сами в цикле добавили его всем элементам документа...

Работать с пространствами имен в XLinq можно несколькими способами.

Вариант первый: использовать способ записи пространства имен внутри строки

```
Document.Element("{http://somenamespace.ru}FirstElement").With(e => e.Element("{http://somenamespace.ru}InnerElement")).With(e => e.Value)
```

Вариант второй: использовать оператор +, который позволяет сложить `XNamespace` и строку чтобы получить `XName`:

```
private static readonly XNamespace NS = "http://somenamespace.ru";

// ...

Document.Element(NS + "FirstElement").With(e => e.Element(NS + "InnerElement")).With(e => e.Value)
```

Вариант третий. Если вам пространства имен не нужны совсем и даже мешают (к примеру, приходят документы с разными пространствами имен - но одинаковой структурой) - можно сделать так:

```
var NS = Document.Root.Name.Namespace;

// ...

Document.Element(NS + "FirstElement").With(e => e.Element(NS + "InnerElement")).With(e => e.Value)
```

PS еще одна хитрость: вместо того чтобы писать `.With(e => e.Value)` - можно привести элемент к типу `string`:

```
var result = (string)Document.Element(NS + "FirstElement").With(e => e.Element(NS + "InnerElement"))
```

Подобный набор операторов приведения типа определен для классов `XElement` и `XAttribute`, причем таким образом можно получать не только строковое значение - но и `int` или `bool`. Причем приведение к nullable-типам (таким как `string`, `int?` или `bool?`) работает даже для значения `null`.